# Can you create a custom dimension in GTM and send it to GA4 with custom code? Without having to manually create it inside GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, custom-code, google-analytics-4

I want to send different events tags to GA4 from GTM, and for every custom parameter used, I have to manually create it inside GA4 (to be available in the GA4 UI). Is there a way to custom code it in GTM and create it along with the tag?

Did not find anything that could help.

Comment: Have you looked at the Google Tag Manager documentation? It reads add a Variable and give it the type "Custom JavaScript". You can add any JavaScript that you want in there. See [GTM docs: Custom JavaScript](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362?hl=en&ref_topic=9125128&sjid=3773171783934582007-EU#custom_javascript). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do it via GTM. Either you have to create it manually in GA4 UI or use the [GA4 Admin API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.customDimensions/create) to create it programmatically.

Alternatively, you may try [Google Analytics Utilities](https://github.com/google/google-analytics-utilities) to create custom dimensions/metrics using Google Sheets/Appscript.